# reconstituting variables to create an object , in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a function like so:

```
function1 (arg1) {

   do something with arg1.prop1a and arg1.prop1b

}
```

Thus, this function accepts an object as an argument, and does something with 2 properties of this object.

I want to call `function1` from `function2` and `function2` looks like so:

```
function2(){

    prop2a = 5;
    prop2b = 10;

    ......

    function1(arg2)

}
```

How can I reconstitute prop2a and prop2b into the object arg2 so that `arg2.prop2a = 5` and `arg2.prop2b=10` ?

I've tried the following and they don't seem to be working:

```
var arg2 = {prop2a:5 , prop2b:10};

var arg2 {prop2a:5 , prop2b:10};
```

Comment: This `var arg2 = {prop2a:5 , prop2b:10);` should be working. Can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: Is the fact that you closed your object {} with a parentheses ) a typo?

Comment: @Likwid_T Yes, typo. Good catch. Am correcting.

Answer (score 0):

To declare a function, use `function` keyword.

To create the object literal, use `var arg2 = {prop1a:prop2a, prop1b:prop2b};`

```js
function function1(arg1) {
  alert(arg1.prop1a + ' | ' + arg1.prop1b);
}
var prop2a, prop2b;
function function2() {
  prop2a = 5;
  prop2b = 10;
  var arg2 = {prop1a:prop2a, prop1b:prop2b};
  function1(arg2)
}
function2();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
function function2() {
    var prop2a = 5;
    var prop2b = 10;
    function1({prop2a, prop2b});
}
```

and you need to call `function2` where you need it.